# Sort 2x3 Matrix without using qsort

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array

My teacher has assigned something I can't seem to figure out how to do without using `qsort`. We're given a 2x3 array, and he wants us to sort each row from min to max. I am not allowed to use `qsort` for the purposes of learning; in my opinion, this is difficult.

Here is what I have so far; currently, the program crashes. I assume this is because when it gets to the third column, there isn't anything in a fourth column `[j+1]`, so it returns an error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x[2][3] = { { 2, 3, -1 }, { 0, -3, 5 } }; //2x3 matrix; 2 rows, 3 columns
    void sortMinMax(int b[][3], int numRow, int numColumn); //function prototype

    sortMinMax(x, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}

void sortMinMax(int a[][3], int numRow, int numColumn) {

for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numColumn - 1; j++) {
        if (a[i][j + 1] < a[i][j]) { //swap values if the next number is less than the current number
            int temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];
            a[i][j + 1] = temp;
        }
        printf("%i\t", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return;
}
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: you've identified one error, why not fix it and test again?  i.e. for (int j = 0; j < numColumn - 1; j++)

Comment: You're teacher wants you to teach yourself sorting algorithms, just google common sorting algorithms and find a simple one, look at the pseudo code and implement it.

Comment: If the sizes are constant( always a 2x3 array ) why are you using size parameters in the function?

Comment: You might find it easier to write a function that sorts a single row, and then call that for each row.

Comment: Well your outer loop *will* go out of bounds, start by fixing that. And for the inner loop, when you are on the last iteration, what do you think `j + 1` will give you for value?

Comment: I was testing stuff when I posted that code. I've updated to reflect the most recent changes.

Comment: Now it works--but only sorts the first two columns. It causes the `3` from the first row to not be printed, and it causes the `5` from the second row to not be printed.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe `int i = 0; i <= numRow; i++` should be `int i = 0; i <
   numRow; i++`
2. Why do you have `if(i==0)` & `if(i==1)` if you are doing the same stuff?
3. It looks like you tried to implement bubble-sort-like algorithm, but you do only one pass over the data

Here is an example of bubble sort algorithm

```
for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<n-1; y++)
    {
        if(array[y]>array[y+1])
        {
            int temp = array[y+1];
            array[y+1] = array[y];
            array[y] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Slightly better alternative might be found @ http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort

```
for i = 1:n,
    swapped = false
    for j = n:i+1, 
        if a[j] < a[j-1], 
            swap a[j,j-1]
            swapped = true
    → invariant: a[1..i] in final position
    break if not swapped
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[2][3] = { { 2, 3, -1 }, { 0, -3, 5 } };
    void sortMinMax(int b[][3], int numRow, int numColumn);

    sortMinMax(x, 2, 3);
    for(int i = 0;i<2;++i){
        for(int j = 0;j<3;++j)
            printf("%i\t", x[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void sort3(int a[3]){
    if(a[0] > a[1])
        swap(&a[0], &a[1]);
    if(a[0] > a[2])
        swap(&a[0], &a[2]);
    if(a[1] > a[2])
        swap(&a[1], &a[2]);
}

void sortMinMax(int a[][3], int numRow, int numColumn) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
        sort3(a[i]);
    }
}
```